# Cosmos Changefeed Spark Streaming Stops randomly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming job which reads Cosmos Changefeed data as below, running in a Databricks cluster with DBR 8.2.

```
cosmos_config = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": cosmos_endpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey": cosmos_key,
  "spark.cosmos.database": cosmos_database,
  "spark.cosmos.container": collection,
  "spark.cosmos.read.partitioning.strategy": "Default",
  "spark.cosmos.read.inferSchema.enabled" : "false",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.startFrom" : "Now",
  "spark.cosmos.changeFeed.mode" : "Incremental"
}
```

```
df_ read = (spark.readStream
                 .format("cosmos.oltp.changeFeed")
                 .options(**cosmos_config)
                 .schema(cosmos_schema)
                 .load())
                     
                     
df_write = (df_ read.withColumn("partition_date",current_date())
              .writeStream
              .partitionBy("partition_date")
              .format('delta')
              .option("path", master_path)
              .option("checkpointLocation", f"{master_path}_checkpointLocation")
              .queryName("cosmosStream")
              .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds')
              .start()
            )
```

While the job works well ordinarily, occasionally, the streaming stops all of a sudden and the below appears in a loop in the log4j output. Restarting the job processes all the data in the 'backlog'. Has anyone experienced something like this before? I'm not sure what could be causing this. Any ideas?

```
22/02/27 00:57:58 INFO HiveMetaStore: 1: get_database: default
22/02/27 00:57:58 INFO audit: ugi=root  ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: default   
22/02/27 00:57:58 INFO DriverCorral: Metastore health check ok
22/02/27 00:58:07 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Starting...
22/02/27 00:58:07 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Start completed.
22/02/27 00:58:07 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Shutdown initiated...
22/02/27 00:58:07 INFO HikariDataSource: metastore-monitor - Shutdown completed.
22/02/27 00:58:07 INFO MetastoreMonitor: Metastore healthcheck successful (connection duration = 88 milliseconds)
22/02/27 00:58:50 INFO RxDocumentClientImpl: Getting database account endpoint from https://<cosmosdb_endpoint>.documents.azure.com:443
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the Cosmos Spark connector are you using? Between 4.3.0 and 4.6.2 there were several bug fixes made in the bulk ingestion code path.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12/CHANGELOG.md for more details.

Comment: We're using Cosmos Spark Connector 4.2.0 (com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12:4.2.0) and Databricks DBR 8.2 (Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)